# How can a similarity matrix with groupby be optimized for speed?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy, optimization

I'm trying to search through a list of products and see how many times a person bought either item and both items. Thus, for each session (BSTC) there equation is (Count of BSTC which bought Product A and Product B)/(Count of BSTC which bought Product A or Product B). My main goal is to figure out how to further speed up my code.

I've tried the below, but it runs very slow.

```
for index, row in visits.iterrows():
    base_sku=row['ITEM_CLICKED'] # Retrives 1 SKU at a Time
    for index2, row2 in visits.iterrows():
        comparison_sku=row2['ITEM_CLICKED'] # Retrives another SKU at a Time
        if base_sku<comparison_sku: 
            sessions=visits[visits['ITEM_CLICKED'].map(lambda x: x in [base_sku,comparison_sku])].groupby('BSTC')['ITEM_CLICKED'].apply(lambda x: len(x.unique()))
            if len(sessions.value_counts())>1:
                sim_mat[index][index2]=sessions.value_counts(2)[2]
                sim_mat[index2][index]=sessions.value_counts(2)[2]      
        elif base_sku==comparison_sku:
            sim_mat[index][index2]=1
```

The desired results are a faster timeit time.

Comment: Have you done any profiling to see which parts are the most time consuming?

Comment: Also, it would be good if you included all the necessary code and some data, so that people can actually run and work with your code.